# data is not displayed in the table at MVC array at storyboard and custom cell

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, custom-cell

Using Xcode 5 for iPhone.
I try to display data in a `tableview` from an `array` in MVC (not local array) - but the data is not displayed in the table and appears empty grid.

I'm using `storyboard` (not nib), and `custom cell` (not TableViewController).

Can you please Advise what am I missing? Thanks in advance 

The code looks like this:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section { 

NSLog (@"array count is %i", listRecipes.recipeArray.count);        
return [listRecipes.recipeArray count];
}
```

and also

```
-(UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    static NSString cellIdentifier = @"ListCellIdentifier"; 
    MYCustomListCell* listCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier]; 
    NSString* dataString = listRecipes.recipeArray[indexPath.row]; 
    listCell.listName.text = dataString; 
    listCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:dataString]; 
    return listCell;
}
```

Comment: Show us you code, that could help.

Comment: What does listRecipes.recipeArray.count return? Is it non-zero?

Comment: This prints 0:    NSLog (@"array count is %i", listRecipes.recipeArray.count);

Answer (score 0):

You should add some code to this question.

My guess is that you haven't provided an implementation for UITableViewDataSource's tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

That should likely return the count of objects in your array.